# MongoDB C# 2.0 upgrade

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

We are currently in the process of upgrading the MongoDb c# driver. There used to be "GrdFS" functionality to save large BSON document into chunks. Looks like the 2.0 doesn't have that feature.

We would like to know whether it is still in the scope or when can we expect this feature to be out there?

Much appreciate your response regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the feature here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1191.

It is largely implemented, but we are waiting for the specification to be finalized. It will ship with the 2.1 version of the driver.